# Login to asp.net 4.0 with Android not working?

Tags: asp.net, android, cookies, authentication

I have a website that runs on ASP.NET 4.0.

Unfortunately people with Android phones cannot login. Based on the logs, it could be a cookie/session issue. But I'm a bit lost. I'm using basic form authentication.

Couldn't find anything about this topic in Google either.

It works on Chrome and it also works with the Android Simulator.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: It's 2012 and I'm having exactly the same issue... Some Android versions work, some doesn't... ASP.NET MVC3 app, forms auth, primitive login page. EDIT: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134546/asp-net-forms-authentication-with-android-browser

Comment: No, I didn't follow the issue any further. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most logins now work on the newer version of Android. No idea what it was, but not an issue anymore.